# Suppress value from display but still include in Group Header calculation

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-2013

As shown below, I have a value that I wish to include in group header 1 but suppress from being displayed in Group Header 2.

Is this possible?

[image]

As shown above the Group header #2 SAM includes a value that is suppressed in the report, but shown in the group header #1. However, I also need to group by SAM and the grouping column is shown in the report with suppressed values. 
(shown below as Q1 Target)

[image]

Can I suppress 'BUDGET SAM' from appearing on the report, but still include the underlying value that accompanies it, so I can get the sum of its values and show it in my group header #1 (as q1 targets)

To give you an idea of the underlying data:[image]

To detail what I have already tried:

1. Suppress formula on Group#2 SAM when it equals 'BUDGET SAM'
2. Selection expert to remove 'BUDGET SAM'

Both of which resulted in Q1 target appearing with zero sums.

Edit:

My Suppression formula (which did not give me the correct results)

```
IF {Command.SAM} = "Budget SAM" THEN TRUE
ELSE FALSE
```

Comment: So you want to hide or suppress whole group header row which contains `BUDGET SAM`, if this correct then please share formula you wrote in Suppress Formula field

Comment: @ArsalanKhan I want to suppress the Group Header one when it equals to 'BUDGET SAM' - BUT, I still want the figures that correlate with BUDGET SAM (which are suppressed in Group Header 3) to appear and roll up to the Group Header #1 (They roll up to Q1 Target) -  FYI: There are other values in Group Header #2 that still need to appear

Comment: where you write suppress formula and please you share the formula, if you can because I implemented your scenario and done

Comment: @ArsalanKhan I have added it to my question.

Comment: I recommend below answer, It hide Group Header section if true

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Section Expert` Click on `Group Header 2` or which you want to suppressed on that window, and then click `Suppress Formula button` and then write the formula like below:

```
GroupName ({DataSetName.SAM}) = 'BUDGET SAM';
```

and then click OK and its done.